# routable modal in ember using ember modal dialog

Tags: javascript, ember.js, modal-dialog, ember-cli

I want to create the routable modal.For that I understand that I have to create nested route  inside a parent routes to work.Something Like this.

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('posts', { path: '/' }, function() {
    this.route('show', { path: '/posts/:post_id' });
  })
```

In this "show" route is routable modal and when user move to `post/id` it open a modal.This is cool and I am able to do it.The problem I am facing is I have component top-Navbar which is static and contains a icon for notification dropdown.The dropdown contains option which should open a modal box to show the image.It is exactly similar to fb notification.Now I have given a action for opening image modal.This is working fine.But when right clicks and try to open the image modal it gets screwed up.I can solve this by using routable modal.Now I have three routes present in

Router.js

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('myprofile',{path:'/mystudio'});
  this.route("usrprofile",{path:'/usrprofile/:id'});
  this.route("feed",path:'/feed'})
});
```

Now I can create a new route for image modal.But in this it will leave  the current route and move to specified route.Which I don't want.It should Open in the current route and when user does a right click it should move to specified routes and open a modal dialog box.I want the features to exactly like facebook.How should I attain this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a good reason why the image modal has to be route-based, I think your best course of action would be to send an action from your navbar component up to whatever is the parent route and open a modal there, passing the modal the image's URL to display.

The only thing that you're giving up in this case, is the ability to copy the URL while the image is open and later visit that same image with the URL you copied.

If that's important, you do have a good reason for using a route-based modal, and in that case you should look at [liquid-fire](https://github.com/ember-animation/liquid-fire) (this option was suggested by @alexspeller in the Ember community slack group)